# Can a testing management tool support automated testing?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, jira, agile

I'm currently at a crossroads with my team as we aim to enhance our testing processes. With the increasing complexity of our projects, manual testing alone is no longer sufficient to ensure quality and efficiency. Therefore, we're exploring the possibility of integrating automated testing into our workflow. However, our main concern lies in managing this transition smoothly, particularly in how automated testing can be supported or integrated with testing management tools.

We want to maintain rigorous testing standards while improving our testing efficiency and coverage. Automated testing seems to be a promising avenue, but we're unsure about the compatibility and integration capabilities of current testing management tools with automated testing frameworks or systems.

We're keen on learning from the community's experiences and insights. If you have successfully navigated this transition or have expertise in this area, your guidance would be invaluable to us.

Looking forward to your recommendations and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Wrong site mate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, a testing management tool can indeed support automated testing. Based on the information provided, it's clear that there's a plan to incorporate automation testing features into the tool. Specifically, the tool aims to facilitate integration with Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment (CI/CD) pipelines and leverage Behavior-Driven Development (BDD) to map user stories. The use of Cucumber for automation suggests a focus on supporting readable and understandable test scripts, which can bridge the gap between technical and non-technical team members. Additionally, with automation testing listed as a "next planned feature" alongside UI/UX improvements, it indicates ongoing development efforts to enhance the tool's capabilities in supporting automated testing effectively. Some of the good tools that I have been using for a while are AgileTest and TestRail they both work well.